# Get upper left corner position of the JPopupMenu object

Tags: java, swing, jpopupmenu

I have a JPopupMenu object. Its behavior depends on its coordinates.
How can I get its position relatively to its parent container?

Comment: For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your `MouseListener`'s method (mouseReleased etc.) you should receive a `MouseEvent` object containing the current position. If you don't want to use those values you can try using the [`Component#getLocation`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/Component.html#getLocation%28%29) method, otherwise the [`Component#getLocationOnScreen`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/Component.html#getLocationOnScreen%28%29) but it returns the absolute position, then you need to calculate the relative one.

Comment: It returns x=0 and y=0. During debugging I noticed that only private field desiredLocation stores the needed value. But I don't know yet how to access it.

Comment: @Andrei How do you get it showed? you should have some code that shows the menu on the correct position, right?

Comment: There is a JPanel, that handles the right click and shows this popup menu.

Comment: @Andrei Your JPanel has a MouseListener I guess. In your MouseListener's method (mouseReleased etc.) you should receive a MouseEvent object containing the current position. Aren't you showing the JPopUpMenu on that position?

Comment: yep, but I wanted to retrieve the position using only the reference to the popup menu object.

Comment: I updated my answer, I'm not sure it will be useful but I hope so. I think you should add some more details to your question to let us understand what you want to achieve. Unfortunately I understood from your comments, not from your question. Maybe someone else can help you more than me.

Answer (score 0):

There is a solution, but it is not recommended, because if there is a SecurityManager it may fail (force the field to be accessible):

```
public static Container getTopParent(@Nonnull Component c) {
    Container lastNotNull = (Container) c;
    Container p = c.getParent();
    if (p != null)
        lastNotNull = p;
    while(p != null) {
        lastNotNull = p;
        p = p.getParent();
    }
    return lastNotNull;
}

public static int getClickedXThatInvokedPopup(@Nonnull ActionEvent ev) {
    try {
        JPopupMenu topParent = (JPopupMenu) getTopParent((Component) ev.getSource());
        java.lang.reflect.Field fieldX = topParent.getClass().getDeclaredField("desiredLocationX");
        fieldX.setAccessible(true);
        int x = (Integer) fieldX.get(topParent);
        Point p = new Point(x, 0);
        SwingUtilities.convertPointFromScreen(p, topParent.getInvoker());
        return p.x;
    } catch(NoSuchFieldException | SecurityException | IllegalArgumentException | IllegalAccessException ex) {
        System.err.println("Cannot get clicked point: " + ex);
        return -1;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Since neither the [`Component#getLocation`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/Component.html#getLocation%28%29) nor the [`Component#getLocationOnScreen`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/Component.html#getLocationOnScreen%28%29) method worked for me, and the fields `desiredLocationX`/`desiredLocationY` are not accessible, I extended JPopupMenu() as follows:

```
contextMenu = new JPopupMenu(){
    private Point desiredLocation;

    /**
    * Override Component#getLocation, since it always returns 0,0.
    */
    @Override
    public Point getLocation() {
        return desiredLocation;
    }

    @Override
    public void show(Component invoker, int x, int y) {
        desiredLocation = new Point(x, y);
        super.show(invoker, x, y);
    }
};
```